# Is multiple LEFT JOINS on same table efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to deal with the following schema (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE user
    (`id` int,
     `name` varchar(255),
     PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE user_extra
    (`user_id` int,
     `user_extra_name` varchar(64),
     `value` varchar(255),
     UNIQUE INDEX user_id_extra_name (user_id, user_extra_name));

INSERT INTO user
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'John Doe'),
    (2, 'Don Joe');

INSERT INTO user_extra
  (`user_id`, `user_extra_name`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 'phone', '1234444'),
    (1, 'email', 'doe@example.com'),
    (2, 'email', 'joe@example.com'),
    (1, 'nickname', 'johnny'),
    (2, 'nickname', 'donny');
```

I want to get the following data in the most efficient way possible:

```
id  name        phone   email               nickname
1   John Doe    1234444 doe@example.com     johnny
2   Don Joe     (null)  joe@example.com     donny
```

There will be many users and potentially more extra entries, besides phone, email and nickname.

What I do so far is multiple left joins on user_extra:

```
SELECT
  u.id, u.name,
  uephone.value AS phone,
  ueemail.value AS email,
  uenick.value AS nickname
FROM
  user u
LEFT JOIN
  user_extra uephone ON
    uephone.user_id = u.id AND
    uephone.user_extra_name = 'phone'
LEFT JOIN
  user_extra ueemail ON
    ueemail.user_id = u.id AND
    ueemail.user_extra_name = 'email'
LEFT JOIN
  user_extra uenick ON
    uenick.user_id = u.id AND
    uenick.user_extra_name = 'nickname'
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Is this liable to cause performance issues as the number of users grow or if there would be, say, a dozen such left joins?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87b97/1)

Comment: Are you using it like this and does it cause you problems at the moment? If not, there is not necessarily a need for premature optimization - it may be better to keep a slightly less performant but also less complex solution over a 'smarter' one if that doesn't cause a performance problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you published *simplified* tables schema (with no index) I can not really say if your query has any performance issue. Probably if `user.id` is primary key and `user_extra.user_id` is indexed as well your query is pretty good.

And if you will add complex index to `user_extra` against `(user_id,user_extra_name)` that could be even better.

But for small tables and just to simplify reading this query here is another approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ab56b/20

```
SELECT
  u.id, u.name,
  ue.phone,
  ue.email,
  ue.nickname
FROM
  user u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    user_id,
    MAX(IF(user_extra_name = 'phone',`value`,null)) AS phone,
    MAX(IF(user_extra_name = 'email',`value`,null)) AS email,
    MAX(IF(user_extra_name = 'nickname',`value`,null)) AS nickname
  FROM user_extra
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) ue
ON
    ue.user_id = u.id
```

But really, if you have indexes on your table I believe your query is good.

Comment: I checked and the existing schema indeed has a primary key on the user table and a complex index on user_extra, just like it should. Thanks for your advice/reassurance :)

Answer (score 1):

The question boils down to you - do you notice any bottlenecks in your application due to this snippet of SQL?

Alex's answer is a great way to go, but if you feel like using `CASE`'s, then a solution like this could suit you well! It only requires one `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  u.id, u.name,
  (CASE WHEN uextra.user_extra_name = 'phone' THEN uextra.value ELSE null END) AS phone, 
  (CASE WHEN uextra.user_extra_name = 'email' THEN uextra.value ELSE null END) AS email, 
  (CASE WHEN uextra.user_extra_name = 'nickname' THEN uextra.value ELSE null END) AS nickname
FROM
  user u
LEFT JOIN
  user_extra AS uextra
ON
  uextra.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
  u.name
ORDER BY
  u.id
ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ab56b/28

Not knowing much about your index's either.

Comment: This would be beautiful, but each result row only seems to pick up the value of the first user extra field :(